# Suddenly can't open folder - access denied

Tags: windows-10

I suddenly can't interact with a certain folder.

**Right click on folder -> Properties -> Security -> Advanced**

And I also can't change the user, even though I have administrator rights (But no domain admin)

[image]

[image]

I already restarted windows.

This is what I get from `ls -lah` from a linux shell terminal:

```
d????????? ? ?     ?       ?            ? CronjobManager
```

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot take ownership of the file (Sie können das Eigentum an der Datei nicht übernehmen) when you say that you cannot "change the user"

Comment: Yes. I can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the tool [unlocker](https://www.netzwelt.de/download/4140-unlocker.html).

Comment: Please click the green checkmark next to your answer to signify that this question has a known/accepted answer.

Comment: You must be new. It only works after 2 days.

Comment: I am very new. Thanks for correcting me instead of criticizing me :D

Comment: No problem. Welcome :)